# Update statement works in Oracle 9i but not in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm facing an issue with an update statement that worked earlier in Oracle 9i but now it does not update any rows in Oracle 11G. Here is the statement that i'm using.

```
update account  
set 
  days_to_validate = validated_date - val_requested_Date 
where 
  validated_date >= val_requested_date
```

The `validated_date` and `val_requested_date` are both date fields in the format: `dd-mmm-yyyy` (18-Mar-2015). This was working earlier in Oracle 9i before we did an upgrade.

Pls advice on how we can fix this.

Thanks
Prashanth

Comment: are they date fields? Or are they varchar fields storing dates?

Comment: Please provide definition of `account` table, e.g. `create table` statement.

Comment: Hello Guys, I was able to fix this. I tried including the "to_date" function and it worked in Oracle 11G. Here is the change i made to the query.

Comment: Missed the query in my earlier comment: update account  set days_to_validate=to_date(validated_date)-to_date(val_requested_Date) where to_Date(validated_date)>= to_date(val_requested_date)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this. I tried including the "to_date" function and it worked in Oracle 11G. Here is the change i made to the query.

```
update account
    set days_to_validate = to_date(validated_date) - to_date(val_requested_Date)
  where to_Date(validated_date) >= to_date(val_requested_date)
```

Comment: To be completely safe you should give the format in the `TO_DATE()` function as well - e.g., `TO_DATE(validated_date, 'dd-mmm-yyyy')`